# is it possible to have a circular dependency between .java and .scala classes?

Tags: java, scala, compiler-construction, scala-java-interop

Lets say I have class A defined in .java file, and class B defined in .scala file.
class A use class B and class B use class A.
If I use java compiler I will have a compilation error because class B is not compiled yet. If I use scala compiler class A will not be found. Is there a compiler that can compile both together?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I thought that Scala 2.7.2 introduced a [joint compilation mode](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/joint-compilation-of-scala-and-java-sources) to do exactly this?

Which version of `scalac` are you using, and is it running with this mode disabled?

Edit: Wait a second, when you say scalac leads to Class A not being found - did you realise that you still need to compile the pure Java files with `javac` afterwards?  Scalac's joint compilation mode doesn't actually produce `*.class` output for the Java files, merely compiles the Scala classes against their signatures.  Hence you still need to compile the Java files afterwards, though this shouldn't be a problem for `javac` now that the Scala classes have been compiled.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted to know. It is just theoretical question after a lecture I have been in.

Answer (score 1):

Create fake class B in Java. Declare there only members which are referenced from A. Methods' bodies can be empty.
Compile A.java and B.java together. Then throw away B.class and compile B.scala.