# Scala cannot reference Java classes

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I have a Java framework for a chess AI server.  I'm planning on using Scala to write the logic for my chess AI.  So I need to edit the "AI" class of the framework to call my Scala code.

My problem occurs when I try to reference a class from the java framework in Scala and I get an error that follows this pattern:

```
class * in package * cannot be accessed in package *
```

the most relevant thing I could find was this:
[What are the guarantees for scala access qualifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712506/what-are-the-guarantees-for-scala-access-qualifiers) , however that doesn't help me at all.

next I found this: [is it possible to have a circular dependency between .java and .scala classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464059/is-it-possible-to-have-a-circular-dependency-between-java-and-scala-classes/4464076#4464076) 
I'll try setting up a maven solution, but eventually I'll need to compile it using make, and run it using a shell script

Creating dummy classes seems like a poor solution.  I don't want to keep editing the framework, recompiling it, and fixing any complaints it has about calling my Scala classes.

I'm a bit confused as to why this is a problem.  I can call any native Java function using Java syntax, no problem.  Why does this happen, even when I've put the framework in a jar and referenced it that way?

Comment: It's hard to tell without even knowing anything about the java and scala code in question. You'll want to provide more information if you expect any ojective answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the particular class(es) are package private. Please make them public and then report back.

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like that worked.  I'm a bit embarrassed because I checked all the classes for `private` and didn't see it before asking the question, but they were all set to default visibility.

Comment: no problem here, i finally get some points, quite a few questions answered few accepted. thx for accepting.